# My function to check for ajax on a page is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

I am making a django project where there is a search/filter dropdown for a form. I am using select2 and ajax. It isn't working, and when I try to debug with print statements, it seems that the is_ajax(request) function is not returning true.

I know the is_ajax() function was deprecated in JQuery, which is why I defined it myself. However, mine doesn't seem to work either.

Here is the portion my view that filters objects:

```
@login_required
def job_application_create(request):
    form = JobApplicationForm()
    if is_ajax(request):
        print('TESTING TESTING TESTING TESTING TESTING TESTING TESTING TESTING ')
        term = request.GET.get('term')
        companies = Company.objects.filter(name__icontains=term)
        response_content = list(companies.values())
        return JsonResponse(response_content, safe=False)
```

and here is the is_ajax(request) definition:

```
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

I also tried this function:

```
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Here is the JS in the page that has my form:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#id_company').select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: "{% url 'homepage' %}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {id: item.id, text: item.name};
                            })
                        };
                    }
                },
                minimumInputLength: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check whether your request is ajax or not.

```
if request.is_ajax():
   pass
```

Not needed additional function to check whether your request is ajax or not.